# SQL Server 2008 R2: LEFT JOIN IS NULL and NOT IN with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables namely test1 and test2, 
I want to display records from test1 which are not present in the test2.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
    cola int,
    colb varchar(10)
);
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE test2
(
    cola int,
    colb varchar(10),
    colc varchar(10)
);
```

Insert records:

```
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');

INSERT INTO test2 VALUES(5,'a','W1'),(2,'b','Z1'),(6,'c','X1');
```

Query 1: Using LEFT JOIN IS NULL and two condition in **WHERE** clause

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test1 t1
LEFT JOIN test2 t2
ON t1.cola = t2.cola 
WHERE t2.cola IS NULL AND t2.colc IN ('Z1','X1')
```

Output:

```
cola    colb
--------------
```

Query 2: Using LEFT JOIN IS NULL and two condition in **ON** clause

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test1 t1
LEFT JOIN test2 t2
ON t1.cola = t2.cola AND t2.colc IN ('Z1','X1')
WHERE t2.cola IS NULL
```

Output:

```
cola    colb
--------------
1       a
3       c
```

Query 3: Using NOT IN

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test1 t1
WHERE t1.cola NOT IN (SELECT cola FROM test2 WHERE colc IN ('Z1','X1'))
```

Output:

```
cola    colb
------------
1       a
3       c
```

Questions:

1. What is wrong with query 1?
2. Which one is true, if we have multiple condition from both tables?
3. Which one is the best for huge data retrieval? (Query 2 OR Query 3)

Comment: as Hồng Văn Vít sad: left join not equal vs where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your first query you have

   WHERE t2.cola IS NULL AND t2.colc IN ('Z1','X1')

If t2.cola is null then t2.colc will also be null(all fields will be in fact), it cannot be null and have another value, that's why you are not getting results

2. not sure what you are asking here
3. you will have better performance by using joins in query 2

Answer (score 1):

**Question1**: Left join combine the records of T1 with the records of T2 and it produce a cartesian product. Your problem is with the `Where` condition.

Try to execute the query without `WHERE` condition, you can see the result set on which the WHERE condition works.

Anyway, the query runs properly.

**Question2**: The filter in the LEFT JOIN Condition DOES NOT FILTER the initial result set. Records are combined and then Filtered by the WHERE clause.

Also there, the query runs properly.

There is not a wrong or right query, it depends on what you want the query to do...

**Question3**: There is not a best choice for big data retrieval. Both the queries are well coded but the second is better. The most of the lacks of performance in SQL Queries comes from lack of indexes in the fields used in the JOIN or in WHERE conditions.

You can also include execution plan in the query output to compare the two query.
For sure the query2 works better than query3

Answer (score 0):

reason is: condition left join or join != condition where. => Query 1 <> query 2 <> query 3

with query 1 you can see:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.colc
FROM test1 t1
LEFT JOIN test2 t2
ON t1.cola = t2.cola 
WHERE t2.cola IS NULL
```

No t2.colc IN ('Z1','X1').

and

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.colc
FROM test1 t1
LEFT JOIN test2 t2
ON t1.cola = t2.cola 
WHERE  t2.colc IN ('Z1','X1');
```

No t2.cola IS NULL

In query 2: If you change left join to join => Query 2 = Query 1